# C++ class name conflict

Tags: c++, c, class, stl

I am now working on a project that needs the integration of two sub-projects.

Project A is written in C++ and project B is written in C. One problem is that in project B, there is a struct called `vector` which is created by its author and in project A, the `std::vector` in `STL` is used. Because project B may be updated later, I don't want to change the name of B's vector class.

Is there a way to deal with such a case?

Comment: How can you have a "class called `vector`" in a C project? There are no classes in C.

Comment: @anthropomorphic sorry that I made a mistake. It should be a struct. I have modified that.

Comment: One more comment. At present, I try to compile the `c` project (project B) into a library and invoke the functions in project A.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you have [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx) in C++! It is advisable to wrap your own `vector` class inside your own namespace.

Comment: Note that there are no namespaces in C. But there also are no classes in C, which makes the OP's question highly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

They're already different names, `vector` and `std::vector` respectively. You don't have to change anything.

Comment: Thanks. But I would also like to ask what if in project A, we write `using namespace std;` and then simply use `vector` instead of `std::vector`. Will there be compiling error in such a case?

Comment: Yes, but you might be easily punned by ADL.

Comment: @Chitanda Never write `using namespace std;`

Comment: @Chitanda, The answer you're probably looking for is type aliasing (`using ...=...` in C++11, or just a plain old `typedef` if needed, along with the global namespace `::vector` and `std::vector<>` respectively), but the real answer is think twice how needed all of this mess you're writing is. Do you really need a structure to have the name of a well known C++ standard class AND do you really need to import the entire `std` namespace every time?

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, it is always good to include the namespaces. However, omitting them sometimes does make the code more clear and easier to understand.

Comment: @Blindy Thanks for advice. I will try your method. Actually, neither of the these two projects are done by me, so it is out of my control. For myself, I will try avoiding such ambiguous names:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are merging 2 projects like this you will be of course programming in C++...

You can wrap the C vector in a namespace... Whenever you need to use the C vector you call its type as C_NAMESPACE::vector. (Don't import both namespaces!)

Try that and see if it works. =)

Comment: So the `C_NAMESPACE::vector` is just the text itself, right? Or `C_NAMESPACE` refers to something else?

Comment: It has no meaning, it is just a random identifier... Wrap your C code with "namespace MyNameSpace { " ... C code .... " }" and call C vector as MyNameSpace::vector. (or <any other name you want to give>::vector)

Comment: Or even better, `namespace ProjectB { extern "C" { #include <projectB_file.h> } }`

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are two very simple solutions.

1. Refrain from `using namespace std;` and refer to the Standard Library's vector as `std::vector`, and the C vector as either `vector` or `::vector`.
2. (If you insist on polluting your project's namespace with the contents of `std`) refer to the Standard Library's vector as either `vector` or `std::vector`, and the C vector as `::vector`.

If you didn't already know, any identifier `x` declared outside of any namespace can be referred to as `::x`, which is *always* distinct from any identifier `x` declared inside of a namespace.

*My* preference in this case would be to avoid writing `vector` anywhere at all, so as to avoid confusion. I would *always* refer to the Standard Library's vector as `std::vector` and the C vector as `::vector`. If you do that it doesn't even matter if you are `using namespace std;` or not.